How can you type 3 paragraphs about being prompt and present at school?
How can you type 3 paragraphs about being prompt and present at school?

Welcome to Writing.SE! What exactly is it that you're having trouble with when trying to write these paragraphs? It's hard to provide help if we don't know what kind of help it is that you need exactly.

I guess you have to write a short essay for school, right?
So begin by collecting all ideas that you have about your topic. Take a piece of paper and write down everything that comes to mind. What does it mean to be prompt and present at school? I imagine something like being alert and attentive in class, doing your tasks immediately, and so on. Maybe also how you behave in school outside of class, towards teachers and classmates, how you handle your things, being punctual, etc. Just take some time and collect everyting that comes to mind until you have a list of a dozen or so things.
Now order these ideas into groups. Some ideas will have to do with class, others with how to treat teachers. If you are supposed to write three paragraphs, try and make three groups of ideas.
For every group, order the ideas by whatever you find logical. For example, begin with attention, then how you respond to what you are attentive towards, then how you do the tasks your are given, then how you keep your notebooks and stuff. Here I ordered the ideas according to the order of what happens in class (the teacher says something, you listen to it, then you do what he or she told you to do etc.). You can use another order, if it feels better to you or fits your ideas better.
Now that you have three groups of ideas and have ordered your ideas within each group, just write one sentence of each idea. Connect the sentences with "and" or "but" or "on the other hand" and other connecting words and phrases.
That's it. You are done!
